# Splitting lines with polygons in PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I have a a large line network (white lines) with 33,000 features that I would like to intersect with each polygon grid cell (black lines) and join the 'description' attribute of the polygon cells to each split line segment.

```
CREATE INDEX lsd_poly_geom_idx ON public.lsd_poly USING GIST (geom);
CREATE INDEX pipelines_geom_idx ON public.pipelines USING GIST (geom);

CREATE TABLE split_lines AS -- table of all lines split by polygon cells
    SELECT p.descriptor, l.*, (ST_Dump(ST_intersection(p.geom, l.geom))).geom as split
    FROM   public.pipelines AS l,
           public.lsd_poly AS p
    ;
```

The resulting table split_lines when imported into qgis doesn't have split lines.  However, I see two other generated layers not shown in the database: split_lines.geom and split_lines.split.  The *.split feature layer is the correctly split one.

How do I save the result into the split_lines table?

[image]

Comment: I tihnk you aready have. But your output table has multiple geometries: the one from `l.geom` (since you selected `l.*`) and another geometry called `split`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `l.*` and `split` is bringing in both the original geometry of the lines (`geom`) as well as the split version (`split`).

What information do you need to retain from the lines?
If just the geometry after split then this is what will work;
*(if other fields are required then specify them instead of using `l.*`.*

```
CREATE TABLE split_lines AS -- table of all lines split by polygon cells
SELECT p.descriptor, (ST_Dump(ST_intersection(p.geom, l.geom))).geom as geom
FROM   public.pipelines AS l,
       public.lsd_poly AS p;
```

Comment: Is there a performance fix for this operation?  I have 315,000 line features across 4,829,485 polygons (400mx400m).  Would converting the polygon grid to lines improve the performance?  I just need to have the lines cut so that I can place a midpoint point on each line segment within the bounds of the polygon.  I only need one attribute from the line and one from the polygon.

Comment: Have you added spatial indexes, they will massively increase performance? :
http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/indexing.html

Getting middle point of a line can be done with ST_LineInterpolatePoint(geom, 0.5); run that on the geometry generated by the split.

Comment: I have continued this task in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/453204/use-of-postgis-st-intersection-st-coveredby-for-line-x-polygon-intersection